# TDBChart Delphi using f(x) Function at runtime

Tags: delphi, teechart

How can I chart a function generated at runtime using TDBChart? I've seen references to OnCalculate event, but I cannot find that event in Delphi. How can I configure my own f(x) function?

Thanks, Toby

Comment: http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/Tutorials/tutorial7.htm

Comment: You can always iterate through your function adding points to the chart.

Comment: Pascal does not have `TDBChart` (or any other part of the Delphi VCL/RTL), which means that the Pascal tag does not apply. If your question is about the generic Pascal language, include the Pascal tag. If it's specifically about Delphi and **not** generic Pascal, do not include the Pascal tag.

Answer (score 1):

Find [here](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/Library/TCustomTeeFunction.html) the entry for the TCustomTeeFunction on TeeChart VCL/FMX online documentation.
Basically, you can declare a procedure with the required arguments and you can assign it to your TCustomTeeFunction `OnCalculate` event. Then, you can make it calculate whatever you like. Ie:

```
procedure TCustomFunctionDemo.TeeFunction1Calculate(Sender: TCustomTeeFunction;
const x: Double; var y: Double);
begin
  y:=Sin(x/10);
end;
```